# Why does ExecutorService.submit wrap Errors inside ExecutionException?

Tags: java

It makes sense to wrap non-`Error` exceptions inside `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`, but why are errors (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`) also wrapped inside `ExecutionException`s? Wouldn't it make more sense to throw `Errors` without wrapping them inside `ExecutionException`?

Here is a sample code that demonstrates this if you run it with `-Xmx32m`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        final Runnable memoryEater = () -> {
            final ArrayList<String> fatList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                for (long j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    fatList.add(String.valueOf(i));
                }
            }

            System.out.println(fatList.size());
        };

        executor.submit(memoryEater).get();
    }

}
```

The logic is inside `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask#report`:

```
/**
 * Returns result or throws exception for completed task.
 *
 * @param s completed state value
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private V report(int s) throws ExecutionException {
    Object x = outcome;
    if (s == NORMAL)
        return (V)x;
    if (s >= CANCELLED)
        throw new CancellationException();
    throw new ExecutionException((Throwable)x);
}
```

Comment: What's your reasoning?

Comment: (a) It doesn't: that is the work of another method. (b) Because that's the way they designed it.

Comment: @shmosel `Error`s indicate states from which an application can not recover, consequently catching them and wrapping them inside another exception class doesn't make sense. In this case, the caller might catch `ExecutionException` and assume a task execution failed and then retry the task, but that would be wrong as due to the error, the JVM should terminate and do not accept more work. From the docs: _"an Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions..."_.

Comment: @shmosel when the error is wrapped inside another exception, the only way to find out that an error is happened is by catching that exception which is not conforming to the way `Error`s should be treated.

Comment: @EJP Java and the JFC have had hundreds of design problems that have either been a) treated as a bug and fixed or b) deprecated  or c) redesigned from scratch. For example, the Java memory model had lots of holes in it so if I remember correctly in Java 5 they wrote a specification for it and greatly improved it. Or the event handling model in Swing got redesigned too. Just because its design is like this at the moment is in no way a proof that the design is correct. If you read my comments, it seems to to be a bug in the design of `Future`s. Unless you can elaborate why the design is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless proven otherwise, this seems to be due to poor design/implementation.